# JavaFX TableView: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: sql, javafx, jdbc

I am attempting to populate a JavaFx TableView with some data from a MySQL query run through JDBC. I previously had no problem with populating the table, until I changed the query to select all columns in the table except one of them. The query runs perfectly in MySQL Workbench.

This is the portion of my code responsible for populating the TableView:

```
ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
TableView table = new TableView();
// rs is the ResultSet returned by executing the SELECT query that should be filling the table
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
for(int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
    final int j = i; 
    TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));
    col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
            // The line below is Main.java:194, the problem source according to the stack trace
            return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
        }
    }); 
    table.getColumns().addAll(col); 
}

while(rs.next()){
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for(int i = 1 ; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
    row.add(rs.getString(i));
}
data.add(row);
}
table.setItems(data);`
```

The stack trace indicates that the problem lies at the line indicated in the snippet. And here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at socparser.Main$2.call(Main.java:194)
    at socparser.Main$2.call(Main.java:1)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:563)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.resizeColumnToFitContent(TableViewSkin.java:241)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.resizeColumnToFitContent(TableViewSkin.java:54)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.doColumnAutoSize(TableColumnHeader.java:531)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.updateScene(TableColumnHeader.java:474)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.handlePropertyChanged(TableColumnHeader.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.lambda$new$49(TableColumnHeader.java:149)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.Node$ReadOnlyObjectWrapperManualFire.fireSuperValueChangedEvent(Node.java:831)
    at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:881)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:919)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onChanged(Parent.java:269)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$29(TrackableObservableList.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.setAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:90)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.updateContent(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:487)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.updateTableColumnHeaders(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:317)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.checkState(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:544)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.computePrefHeight(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:427)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:929)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1435)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computePrefHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:331)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computeMinHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:324)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:957)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1401)
    at javafx.scene.control.SkinBase.computeMinHeight(SkinBase.java:254)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.computeMinHeight(Control.java:489)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:957)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1401)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.computePrefHeights(GridPane.java:1424)
    at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.layoutChildren(GridPane.java:1690)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at socparser.Main$2.call(Main.java:194)
    at socparser.Main$2.call(Main.java:1)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:563)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:533)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
    at javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9153)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1964)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1797)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1879)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2528)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Complete code is unavailable but check your code **at socparser.Main$2.call(Main.java:194)**. Also, I reckon, you may be referencing arrays / elements that are 0 and 1 based incorrectly. While ReseultSet and ResultSetMetadata columns are 1 based, inbuilt types are not.

Comment: I guess I should have specified, Main.java:194 is the line `return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());` in my code snippet. In that snippet, I iterate over ResultSetMetadata columns starting from 1. Everywhere else, I begin at 0 as usual.

Comment: Ok in that case could the index be **j-1**? like **SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j-1).toString())**

Comment: @Gro That was it! Thank you! `final int j = i;` needed to be `final int j = i - 1;` to bridge the difference between the ResltSetMetaData index and the inbuilt index used by the cell value factory callback function on line 194. If you'd like, you can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to either

- change SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(**j**).toString()) to 
  SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(**j-1**).toString())
  or
- final int j = i; to final int j = i - 1;